# Проблемы с gettext php

Tags: php, локализация, locale, gettext

Не работает перевод текста через gettext. Помогите пожалуйста

```
$translate = 'messages';

putenv("LC_ALL=ru_RU");
T_setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU");

bindtextdomain($translate, _ROOT_DIR_."locale/");
textdomain($translate);
bind_textdomain_codeset($translate, 'UTF-8');
```

Структура папок :

> locale ->
>               ru_RU ->
>                       LC_MESSAGES ->
>                                       messages.mo
>                                       messages.po

Код `messages.po` :

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"

"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-05-03 13:06+0300\n"

"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-05-03 13:06+0300\n"

"Last-Translator: \n"

"Language-Team: \n"

"Language: ru_RU\n"

"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"

"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"

"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.1\n"

"X-Poedit-Basepath: ../../..\n"

"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n"

"%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);\n"

"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: index.php:5
msgid "Hello world"
msgstr "Привет мир"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было просто закомментировать одну строку в файлу php.ini. Вот так -

```
;extension=php_gettext.dll
```